# Getting an SVN version of a certain file

Tags: tortoisesvn

I would like to present in my GUI the SVN version of a certain file added to the project without hard-coding it each time I change something in the file and re-upload it to the SVN.
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Can you explain, why **revision of single file** in *project* is important for you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Subversion keywords, expressed as subversion properties on the file using the svn:keywords property.  You'd set svn:keywords to Revision or Id to solve your problem. (Note that this solution updates data *in* the file, which is exposed when viewing or editing the file.  It may or may not be shown an any particular GUI which is *not* a file editor.)

For more information on svn:keywords check out [Special Keywords](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html)

For TortoiseSVN, right-button the file, pick TortoiseSVN, Properties, new, Keywords, and check the ones you want applied to the file.

Then, in the file, insert (in comments) the special strings $Revision$, $Id$, $Author$, etc. and Subversion will convert those into the actual data when the file is committed.  Then, upon checkout, the data will appear and will be updated on the next commit.

Comment: "You **can**", and - only for text-files

Answer (score 0):

If

- your GUI can communicate with repository (i.e data is Working Copy or
  you know filename-URL relation)

and

- Production system has SVN-client

you can for **any file-type** get file-revision dynamically

`svn ls -v URL` (first column) or `svn info URL` ("Last Changed Rev" string)